# Deleted Anaconda folder, now icannot use python anymore?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

i am a ubuntu beginner,

i deleted the anaconda folder and deleted the mention in bashrc.

but when i type python in terminal, all i get is :

bash: /home/sk/anaconda3/bin/python: No such file or directory

How can i fix that ?

Comment: change the "python" alias to point to another python version? Note that [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour) _may_ be a better place to ask this. However I think that question has been answered already so you might find it by browsing/searching on google, stackoverflow or superuser.

Comment: Reinstall anaconda. It's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit `~/.bashrc` and remove the anaconda directory from your `PATH`environment variable, and remove the hidden `.condarc` file and `.conda` and `.continuum` directories which may have been created in the home directory with `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`

Also you may use `hash -r` to clear and refresh the locations of commands

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean how can i get python to work on this machine again, I'd open up the package manager and force an uninstall and then reinstall python.